# Changing flights after receiving Chinese visa (and some other questions)

Tags: visas, china

I'll be applying for a (first time) Chinese tourist visa. Because of my travel itinerary, I'll need a double-entry visa. However, many sources state the consulate will only delivery single-entry ones if you're applying for the first time. Is this true or will I be fine if I can prove I will enter China twice?

Second, I'm a bit confused about the photo requirements. I just went to a photograph to get passport photo's in the format they require and now it seems they just changed the requirements: the visa form V.2013 is not longer accepted. Now, you need to fill in the form on a website, print it out and sign it. The issue is... you need to upload a photo as well. I only have the photo's in paper form. Does that mean I will have to get new passport photo's and ask for a digital copy this time (which also has very specific requirements), along with printed copies (as you still need to provide those as well)? Does anyone have experience with this?

My last question: once my visa is approved, can I change the flight date? I'm considering rebooking my flight to arrive a few days earlier so I have a little more time in China, is this an issue as I need to provide my flight tickets when applying for the visa? I know you can cancel and rebook other hotels, but is it the same with flights?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE.  You appear to have three entirely separate questions, I would suggest asking them separately as well.

Comment: But I'll answer the last Q: once your visa is granted, you're in, nobody will check or care about your flights or even your port of arrival.  You don't even need to show flight tickets if you have another plausible explanation (entering by train, crossing by land, etc).

Comment: @Bv202 Re the last Q, it might be stating the obvious but you can change your initial flight to an earlier date provided you arrive on or after the visa validity start date. Subsequent changes don’t matter, as jpatokal says in the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very common for first time visitors to get dual entry 6 month visas if you can show the need for such visa.

The 1 year multiple entry visa is what is normally restricted for first time visitors.

For the photo yes it is all online and you will need to upload a photo to complete the form now.

Once your visa is granted and valid you can change your flights as you wish within the Valid period of the visa, there is no rules or regulations regarding that once your visa is granted.